# Ephesoft community edition version 4.0.2.1 path is missing, is there a new location to download it

Tags: ephesoft

I am trying to download the Ephesoft community edition version 4.0.2.1 path that is supposed to fix bugs in version 4.0.2.0 , the location on the wiki page (http://download.ephesoft.com/Ephesoft_Product/Ephesoft_v_4.0.2.1/Linux/Ephesoft_Patch_4.0.2.1.zip) does seem to be broken, do we have a correct location?

Comment: did you found any link to download the ephesoft?

Comment: @ShanKhan No, I did not,you have to purchase from Ephesoft to get it sent to you. They kind of make it difficult for someone to get a copy without purchasing